# Maintain Facebook access even when app is killed

Tags: swift2, facebook-ios-sdk

I have implemented Facebook SDK in to my Swift app and have a log in button to redirect the user to Facebook using:

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController:self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            let facebookCancelled = UIAlertController(title: "Facebook Cancelled", message: "You cancelled Facebook sign up.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(facebookCancelled, animated: true, completion: nil)

            facebookCancelled.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
            }))
        }
        else
        {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                // Do work
            }

            self.getFBUserData()
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(normal), email"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")
                self.facebookTestLabel.text = "\(result)"

                //let fullName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                //print("Full name is: \(fullName)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

2 things:

1. How can I maintain the Facebook access token even if my app is killed and reloaded?
2. How can I use the Facebook app if it is installed instead of redirecting to the website?

Thanks :)

Comment: I am not using Facebook SDK on iOS, but I used on Android. And when my phone have Facebook App and it logged in, my application still access FB when open although I kill it.

Comment: Thanks. What I need to do is not access FB, but access the public_profile, image and email from the already authenticated user if I reload my app. If the user logs out of my app I understand I would then need to re-authorise but the user may just restart their phone.

Comment: I am not sure this is good approach or not, but you can save Facebook access token in Keychain. So even you delete your app you can access when you install it again.

Answer (score 0):

That's is happen because you are calling FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() before FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) in the AppDelegate.